# Bucle while no frena

Tags: java, while

Tengo un while con un centinela booleano. Si se introduce un entero, que es lo que se solicita, funciona bien, pero si se introduce cualquier otra cosa el bucle se repite sin fin, imprimiendo la pregunta "escriba 3 números enteros" y " que sea entero". Se supone que la entrada.nextInt debiera poner el programa en espera, pero no se porqué, no pasa.

```java
boolean c=false;

try 
{

    while(!c) 
    {
        System.out.println("Escriba 3 numeros enteros");
        if(entrada.hasNextInt())
        {
            x=entrada.nextInt();
            c=true;
        }
        else 
            System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");
    }
}
catch(InputMismatchException exc) 
{
    System.out.println(exc);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Por qué produce el loop infinito?** El scanner bloquea el programa esperando que se introduzca un dato en el buffer. Cuando se introduce un dato, el buffer deja de estar vacío y el bloqueo termina.Si no es un número, el método `hasNextInt()` devuelve falso, por eso no entra en la condición y continúa con la ejecución del while. Y como no se hizo una lectura al dato introducido, el buffer sigue con un valor. En la siguiente iteración el scanner no bloquea y eso produce el loop infinito.

Lo que falta es, si lo ingresado no es un número entonces leer el dato ingresado para que el buffer quede vacío de nuevo y el scanner bloquee el programa:

```
else {
   System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");
   entrada.nextLine(); //descarta el dato ingresado
}
```

Comment: God!!. Joer que bien!!!!. Gracias. ya había pensado que algo así podría ser pero soy profano. Había intentado el scanner. reset pero no me funcionó. Mil gracias

Comment: Esta es la respuesta que realmente responde a la pregunta y no sugiere cambiar la implementación sin más

Answer (score 3):

Puedes mejor manejar errores

```
    boolean c = false;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entrada;
    Integer x;
    while (!c) {
        System.out.println("Escriba 3 numeros enteros");
        try {
            entrada = scanner.next();
            x = Integer.parseInt(entrada);
            c = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Este funciona. jeje Voy a ver el Integer, No obstante sigo sin entender porque no frena el While. En mi código retorna bien pero no frena a la espera de introducir nuevamente algo en el input

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente estas obteniendo un `InputMismatchException` , esto se debe a que el `Scanner` indica en este caso que el token recuperado no coincide con el  tipo esperado.

Después de este error el `while` continua pero lo que provoca el bucle infinito es que el `Scanner` tiene el valor que se queda en el buffer que no es de tipo entero como se esperaba y el valor de c nunca cambiara a falso.

Lo más común para realizar lo que deseas es determinar cuando se realiza la entrada de la n cantidad de elementos

```
  while (elementos < n) {
    ...
    ...
  }
```

pero en este caso validar primeramente si el elemento es de tipo determinado en este caso entero, lo cual puedes determinarlo de esta forma:

```
      //Ejecuta while si la entrada no es tipo entero.
       while (!entrada.hasNextInt()) {
           System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");                
           entrada.next();
       }
```

Por lo tanto esto sería una opción para resolver el problema:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


    int x = 0;
    int elementos = 0;
    System.out.println("Escriba 3 numeros enteros");

    while (elementos < 3) {

       //Valida si el valor es entero
       //de otra forma muestra mensaje
       while (!entrada.hasNextInt()) {
           System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");                
           entrada.next();
       }
        x = entrada.nextInt();
        entrada.nextLine(); 

        elementos++;//Incrementa variable contador.           
    }

    System.out.println("Termina...");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si colocas mejor el bloque try catch dentro del cuerpo de tu while y no fuera?

```
while(!c) {
    System.out.println("Escriba 3 numeros enteros");

    try{
       if(entrada.hasNextInt()) {
         x=entrada.nextInt();
         c=true;
       }
    }catch(InputMismatchException exc){
       System.out.println("Que sea entero, try again");
    }

}
```

Comment: No funciona tampoco. De hecho así es como lo tenía antes de obtener el fallo